# How send page number in KendoUI Filter in server side

Tags: kendo-ui-grid

I have a kendo grid  my paging is in the server side but the filter is in the client side.
I have a problem with the paging in server side when I change the page number and I try to make a filter, the controller take in his  parameter "paginator " another page number, here is my code:

```
public JsonResult ObtenerFURReporte(string ano_seleccionado, Paginador pagina) {

    try {
        if (ano_seleccionado == null) {
            BoletoAereoBLL boletoBLL = new BoletoAereoBLL();
            var ListaFURReporte = boletoBLL.ObtenerFURReporte(pagina.page, pagina.pageSize, pagina.skip, pagina.take);
            var counter = ListaFURReporte.Item2;
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = ListaFURReporte.Item1, Total = counter }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } else {
            int anoBuscar = Convert.ToInt32(ano_seleccionado);
            BoletoAereoBLL boletoBLL = new BoletoAereoBLL();
            var ListaFURReporte = boletoBLL.ObtenerFURReportePorAno(anoBuscar);
            var counter = ListaFURReporte.Item2;
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = ListaFURReporte.Item1, Total = counter }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

In my configuration in JavaScript:

```
serverPaging: true

  scrollable: true,
        selectable: "simple",
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filterable: {
            extra: false,
            operators: {
                string: {
                    contains: "Contiene"
                }
            }
        },
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
```